# Array destructuring assignment to default parameters: keeping both array and items variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the best of both worlds in one go: individual variables to reference a specific function call result, and an array variable with all those results.

If you paste the code below in your browser console or node runtime it will _just work™ without errors:

```js
function useFieldX() { return { state: 'x' } }
const fields = [ fieldX = useFieldX()]

console.log(fields) // [{ state: 'x' }]
console.log(fieldX) // { state: 'x' }
console.log(fieldX === fields[0]) // true
```

But [bundling/transpiling this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/destructuring-assignment-test-2hgbtt) throws `ReferenceError: fieldX is not defined`. What might be the reason for that?

Note: I understand that `fieldX` variable should in theory be already declared in the current scope to be assigned, but why does it work in the abovementioned contexts though?

```js
function useFieldX() { return { state: 'x' } }
const fields = [ fieldX = useFieldX()]

console.log(fields) // [{ state: 'x' }]
console.log(fieldX) // { state: 'x' }
console.log(fieldX === fields[0]) // true
```

Comment: What's the point of writing `const fields = [fieldX = useFieldX()]` instead of just `const fields = [useFieldX()]`? Besides making your code hard to read?

Comment: The code that originated this question started with just `const fieldX = useFieldX()`. Then it evolved to dozen of similar calls for different "fields", and only recently there was the need to loop over all of them to execute a common task. 

The fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ thing are still used individually.

EDIT: and yes of course we can do `const fields = [fieldX, fieldZ]`, but that's not the point of the OP.

Comment: "But bundling this code" — So you have some working code, but if you transform it using a bundler (which you **haven't named or shown us the configuration for**) then it changes the code (into some different code **that you haven't shown us**) then that other code doesn't work? Not a lot we can do to help given the information we currently have.

Comment: "throwing the fieldX variable is undefined" — Is that the *exact* message that is thrown? What specific line (of the transformed code you haven't shown us) is throwing it?

Comment: @Quentin the assignement line `const fields = [ fieldX = useFieldX() ]` -> `fieldX is undefined`. Here's a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/destructuring-assignment-test-2hgbtt) of the thing, and judging by the console errors it probably is something related to  transpiling. 

The question is precisely about what could be the reason, not that "should we do this code or not".

Comment: You tagged the question with object destructuring and use the term in the title, but I can't find neither object destructuring nor array destructuring in the code. Why did you use this tag? `const fields = [ fieldX = useFieldX()]` isn't destructuring. `const { state } = useFieldX()` is destructuring.

Comment: The error is actually `ReferenceError: fieldX is not defined` which is different than being `undefined`. Also *'If you paste the code below in your ... node runtime it will work as I "expected"'* is a generalization that that would be better stated as 'if run in a non strict mode environment'. As soon as you're using modules everything is strict so will fail with the same error.

Comment: If I knew that _"if run in a non strict mode environment"_ was the cause, I would not have asked the question in the first place, right? Updated the question the proper error identification.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment to implicit globals is forbidden in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which turns several bad practises likely to lead to mistakes into errors. Code just running in a browser or a node repl doesn't run in strict mode.

```js
!function () {
    implicitGlobal1 = 1;
}();

!function () {
    "use strict";
    implicitGlobal2 = 1;
}();
```

Code generated by Parcel (which you should mention in your question and not depend on people to follow a link to your project on a different site and dig around in your package.json to identify) runs in strict mode.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll update the question for posterity with the extra details. My "project" does not use Parcel, the sandbox was just a quick demo. Asking good questions is as hard as providing good answers.

Comment: @renatodeleao Your [mcve] in the link uses Parcel. This is the start script in the `package.json`: `parcel index.html --open`. We can only answer questions based on the details you provide.